# which PHP Framework use for jquery +HTML5 mobile website?

Tags: php, performance, jquery-mobile, frameworks, mobile-website

I have a made website in Zend Framework. Now I am making the same site with less
functionality for mobile phones in jquery + HTML5. But which framework do I need to use for 
this ??

Because ZF slows my website very much, about 92% performance on Y-Slow. I am
afraid  that if I use ZF again it will slow it again on Mobile Phones.

So I need to know which php framework I should use ?? or core php etc

Comment: I think more information as to what you want in a framework would help. For example, why not just use html5 and jquery mobile yourself?  What do you need from a framework?

Comment: i have used php extensively in my site its enterprise level site.so i must do the same site in any php framework

Comment: This is the which-php-framework-is-best question again, and since it is discursive, it isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. I can't think of a reason why _any_ framework could not use HTML or jQuery. -1, sorry. (Post script: YSlow measures your frontend performance, and you can fix that in any framework. Stick with ZF, and optimise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend ZF again .you are making the same site so u have done almost everything
just need to retouch your js and html.try to optimize your PHP code as much as possible and go through ZF again.

kindly study this it will help u alot [Great Stuff](http://www.web-punk.com/2010/03/zend-framework-applications-for-iphone-blackberry-co/comment-page-1/#comment-19503)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Codeigniter.com it is very fast and simple. I am using it right now for a mobile location based application and it works perfectly. The documentation and the large community make it very easy to learn and adapt to your application.

Other fast PHP Frameworks are Yii and FuelPHP.

You could also optimize your Zend framework to save you the trouble of setting up a new website. Depends how many users you are planning on having.